# Hangfire on .netcore not working after a while (deployed to real server)

Tags: c#, vue.js, .net-core, plesk, hangfire

I have set `hangfire` on my `.netcore` project. Every 10 seconds, some codes execute and fetch some data from an api.

In local, everything works fine, but when I deploy the project on real server (Plesk), it stops working after a while.

The frontend is `vue.js`. When I open website (Vue.js) the hangfire works perfectly,but when I close the website, after 5 or 10 minutes, hangfire stop working and no data fetch from the API every 10 seconds.

It seems when there is an interaction with server, hangfire works, but when there is no interaction with server, hangfire stops working.

What did I go wrong?

Comment: What does `when I close the website` mean? Production sites don't close and HangFire has nothing to do with browsers or `Vue.js`. It's a background service. `Plesk` isn't a `real server` either, it's someone else's hosting platform, configured by the hoster according to a hosting plan. Is this a shared hosting plan perhaps, where the hoster aggressively shuts down web apps without traffic?

Comment: thanks for your response.
"when i close the website" means there is no interaction with server. yes its a shared server. so you mean probably the hoster shuts down web apps without traffic ... i don't think so but i will send a ticket and ask them about this. @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: If it's a shared plan they *definitely* shut down sites and serve active sites only. That's what `shared` means. Even dedicated servers run inside VMs. You pay extra because those VMs are always on.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks alot,yes you are right, I will follow up this case. Thanks

Comment: The *real* solution is to either upgrade to a dedicated plan or use the hoster's automation/job scheduling offerings. If they don't have one, you could probably use an external service, or even a cloud service that will call an endpoint in your application every X seconds. The hoster may *not* be happy if one of the shared apps stays on indefinitely though

Comment: Microsoft recommends its own approach https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/net-core-workers-as-windows-services/ So either you use what Microsoft offers, or you stick to Hangfire and all its common issues.

Answer (score 1):

If your Hangfire Server is running in IIS, then it will most definitely lose its heartbeat when the application process idles.

When your IIS hosted application is not receiving any requests, IIS will look to free up resources and close it down. When an incoming request is received by IIS, it then powers that process back up.

The solution, is to have you Hangfire Server hosted separately and run it from command prompt. This ensure that the service doesn't go down.